# Storing user files in folders using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, multer

The app I am building allows users to post ads. Ads allow uploading multiple images. I am trying to put the images uploaded by each user into a respective folder with the folder names of the _id of the Ad that is being inserted in the mongodb.

Here is the route code;

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var mv = require('mv');
var fsex = require('fs-extra')
var fs = require('fs');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var path = require('path');
var Ad = require('../models/ad.model.js');
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'public/images/',
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + Math.random() + path.extname(file.originalname));

    }


});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('adreqform');
});


router.post('/', upload.array('img_', 3), function (req, res) {

    if (req.session.loggedIn) {

        var dateObj = new Date();
        var locale = "en-us";
        var month = dateObj.toLocaleString(locale, { month: "long" });
        var datee = dateObj.getUTCDate();
        var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
        var day = dateObj.getDay();


        var displaydate = datee + " " + month + " " + year;

        var ad = {

            heading: req.body.heading,
            deliverby: req.body.date,
            metal: req.body.metal,
            weight: req.body.weight,
            unit: req.body.unit,
            opdesc: req.body.opdesc,
            userobjid: req.session.user._id,
            username: req.session.user.username,
            deliverydate: req.body.date,
            creationdate: new Date(),
            displaydate: displaydate,
            approvaldate: "Null",
            imgdest: "Null"

        }



        var newad = new Ad(ad);
        newad.save(function (err, newad) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);

            } else {

                Ad.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'creationdate': -1 } }, function (err, latestad) {
                    global.latestad = latestad._id
                    mkdirp('/Users/mesam/source/repos/JewelryMP/JewelryMP/public/images/' + global.latestad, function (err) {
                        if (err) console.error(err)
                        else {
                            fs.rename('public/images/img_.jpg', 'public/images/' + global.latestad + '.jpg', function (err) {
                                if (err) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
                                else {
                                    fsex.move('/Users/mesam/source/repos/JewelryMP/JewelryMP/public/images/' + global.latestad + '.jpg', '/Users/mesam/source/repos/JewelryMP/JewelryMP/public/images/' + global.latestad + '/img.jpg', function (err) {
                                        if (err) return console.error(err)
                                        else {
                                            Ad.findByIdAndUpdate(latestad, { imgdest: '/Users/mesam/source/repos/JewelryMP/JewelryMP/public/images/' + global.latestad + '/img.jpg' }, { new: true }, function (err, w) {

                                                if (err) { console.log(err) }
                                                else {





                                                    console.log('checkimgdest');


                                                }


                                            });
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
                res.redirect('/');
            }

        });


    }
    else console.log('User was not found');

});

router.get('/profile', function (req, res) {



});


module.exports = router;
```

The code above creates the folder with the _id of the Ad and also uploads 3 photos into the directory public/images. What am I not being able to figure out is, how do I then move the three files uploaded to the folder that was created with the _id knowing that there is no connection between the names of the uploaded files.

I might be choosing wrong words to express my issue but here is how clearly I can put. Imagine user1 uploads 3 photos. At this point in time we have 3 images and a folder with the _id at hand. Next moment user2 also uploads 3 photos. At this time we have 2 folders of different _id (rightly so) and 6 photos. How do I figure out a way to move user1's 3 photos to the _id folder that it created and user2's photos to the _id folder that it created. **I can't name the photos with the _id of the Ad because at the time upload.array() gets run it is not available**. First the Ad saves, then the _id in mongodb get's generated and is available to use hence at the time of directory creation it is available (see code).

I need direction dear stackoverflow community! I need direction..

Comment: If you're able to name the photos with the `_id` for the Ad, how does it help for retrieval? What is the `imgdest` field in your model for?

Comment: imgdest field will be an array storing the path of the images. Through handlebars I will be populating it. I have achieved it with single image upload. Only multiple image upload is an issue because I can't find a way to distinguish images uploaded with the _id folder that was created with it.

Comment: @MesamAbbas Why don't you use the object `req.files` to get the list of files uploaded by the user?

Comment: @stdob req.files shows the list of files true. But do what with it? Could you be more elaborate to what are you suggesting?

Comment: @MesamAbbas Each object with a file description inside `router.post('/', upload.array('img_', 3)...` contains the path to where it was eventually uploaded. So you can rename and move only those files that belong to the current upload after get id of the Ad.

Comment: @stdob-- Okay.. you mean something like putting the fs.rename(...) in a loop and renaming req.files.filename with ad._id? Something along those lines?